# Need to separate information in a text file using grep or awk or sed

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, grep

I've a text file **fruits.txt** with the information:

```
15 Apples 0
155 Bananas 0
250 Mangoes 0
555 Oranges 0
```

where the first column with values 15, 155, 250, 222 represent the number of fruits(count) 
second column Apples, Bananas, Mangoes, Oranges represent fruit name
third column 0, 0, 0, 0 represent the type (or some random thing)

I need to extract the content from **fruits.txt** into other separate files based on the count of number of fruits in first column.

For example,
if the count is in b/w 1 to 100, it should be stored in a file **a.txt**
Similarly, b/w 101 to 200 in **b.txt**,
 b/w 201 to 300 in **c.txt** and
b/w 500 to 600 in **d.txt**

Desired output:
a.txt should have the following as its content:

```
15 Apples 0
```

b.txt as:

```
155 Bananas 0
```

c.txt as:

```
250 Mangoes 0
```

d.txt as:

```
555 Oranges 0
```

Any ideas to get the output using sed or awk or grep?

Comment: what happens between 300 and 500?

Comment: @karakfa It's just an example bro. I didn't want to make it too lengthy. :)

Comment: @karafka  about 199 other integers.

Comment: the reason I asked is, if you have no gaps in the range there is a simpler implementation to check only one of the bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk would work well here:

```
awk '$1>=1 && $1<=100 {print > "a.txt"} $1>=101 && $1<=200 {print > "b.txt"} $1>=201 && $1<=300 {print > "c.txt"} $1>=500 && $1<=600 {print > "d.txt"}' fruits.txt
```

This works by specifying where to print the the line inside each `{}` block, and adding a condition in front of each block to limit which records hit the block. For the first file `a.txt` we use the condition `$1>=1 && $1<=100` which says "Test the first field to see if it's between 1 and 100". Then we just repeat for your remaining 3 conditions.

In the end, it's a one-liner that creates 4 files based on your conditions.

Comment: missing redirect before "d.txt".  Tried to edit it, by was denied!

Comment: @Brian Fixed it! Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to do math in sed and grep.
So that leaves awk.  (I'd rather use perl.)

And the requirements are weird.

I'd do something like this:

```
awk '{ if (0 < $1 && 101 > $1) { print $0 > "a.txt" } }
    { if (100 < $1 && 201 > $1) { print $0 > "b.txt" } }
    { if (200 < $1 && 301 > $1) { print $0 > "c.txt" } }
    { if (499 < $1 && 601 > $1) { print $0 > "d.txt" } }' fruits.txt
```

Comment: `if(a) {...}` statement can be simplified as `a{...}` block

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses only Bash.  It does basic error handling.

```
# Initialize output files
for outfile in a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt ; do
    echo >$outfile
done

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]] ; do
    read -r count rest <<<"$line"
    if (( count <= 1 )) ; then
        echo "ERROR - Invalid count in '$line'" >&2
    elif (( count < 100 )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line" >> a.txt
    elif (( count <= 101 )) ; then
        echo "ERROR - Invalid count in '$line'" >&2
    elif (( count < 200 )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line" >> b.txt
    elif (( count <= 201 )) ; then
        echo "ERROR - Invalid count in '$line'" >&2
    elif (( count < 500 )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line" >> c.txt
    elif (( count <= 501 )) ; then
        echo "ERROR - Invalid count in '$line'" >&2
    elif (( count < 1000 )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line" >> d.txt
    else
        echo "ERROR - Invalid count in '$line'" >&2
    fi
done < fruits.txt
```